# .htaccess is acting unexpectedly

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have got a very simple php project containing **three** files named **file.php**, **file-success.php** and **file-failure.php**.

There is a **.htaccess** file inside the root directory having following lines of code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^file-success file-success.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^file-failure file-failure.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^file file.php [NC,L]
```

Surprisingly, **/file-success** is giving me the contents of **file.php**.

But, if I toggle line no. 4 and 5, **/file-failure** is giving me the contents of **file.php**.

What is the reason of this behavior? What concept am I missing?

Comment: 1. the issue at hand is here: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f`, it should be `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f`. Note: that is NOT a matching pattern, but a string concatenation.

Comment: 2. keep in mind that those condition are only applied to a single, following `RewriteRule`. The further rules are _not_ impacted by those conditions. You have to repeat the conditions for all rules.

Comment: Because the pattern is so specific, do we even need `RewriteCond`? I would think `^file$` and `^file-(success|failure)$` would be good enough for rules? Might be able to combine them even

Comment: Why should not ```/file-success``` render the ```file-success.php``` contents? isn't it executed from top to bottom?

Comment: @SouravMalo, as noted, conditions only apply to the first rule found, you need to repeat those conditions again for each each rule. `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f` is literally "if the file `file-success.php` does not exist", but it does, so that condition is skipped.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
> RewriteRule ^file-success file-success.php [NC,L]
> RewriteRule ^file-failure file-failure.php [NC,L]
> RewriteRule ^file file.php [NC,L]
> ```

When you request `/file-success`...

1. The 1st rule rewrites the request to `file-success.php`. Rewrite engine starts over with the use of the `L` flag.
2. The 3rd rule then rewrites `file-success.php` to `file.php`. The regex `^file` matches any URL-path that simply starts with `file`.

You need to be more specific in the regex. ie. include end-of-string anchors. And the preceding *conditions* (`RewriteCond` directives) are not required with such a limited set of rules (the conditions only apply to the first rule anyway).

Use the following instead:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^file-success$ file-success.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^file-failure$ file-failure.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^file$ file.php [NC,L]
```

However, you should avoid the `NC` flag here as it potentially opens you up to duplicate content. And these 3 rules can be combined into one using regex *alternation*, for example:

```
RewriteRule ^(file-success|file-failure|file)$ $1.php [L]
```

The `$1` backreference contains the file basename that's requested, as captured by the `RewriteRule` *pattern*.